Is it possible to delay specific CSS transition properties?
I was wondering if there was a way I could offset / delay specific CSS properties sort of like:
{
  color: red;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 10s ease;

  transition-delay: color 2s;
  transition-delay: top 5s;
}


Does transition: all 10s, top 5s 10s, color 2s 10s not do the trick? You can't actually do it in the transition-delay prop as it only takes a list of delays that match your definitions. Potentially transition: all 10s, top 10s, color 10s and transition-delay: 0s, 5s, 2s would work?

see  this:
 transition-delay: 1s, 250ms;
 transition-property: top, color;

